# How to make vignette effect on background?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a solid color background in game and I want to add to that background a vignette effect. There is any simple way to do that? The collors will change in time so will be nice if the vignette effect will be permament regardless of the background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity's own post-processing stack asset from the asset store provides an option to add a vignette effect.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/post-processing-stack-83912

Here is a video from Brackeys about vignette: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0OQvWAPeuo

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks. So there is any simple metod to do that without asset pack?

Comment: Its an assetpack from Unity itself.  You can implement Vignette effect without writing any code. :) This one is the most simple as per my experience.